# TextArea setText won't show the new Text

Tags: java, view, javafx, textarea, stage

I got some Problems with a TextArea.
I tried to set a new Text after pressing a button.
But the GUI doesn't the new Text. If I check the textarea with get Text(), the console is showing the new Text. So there must be a problem maybe with the View class..

Hope you guys can help me.

Little Codeexplaining:
The Class Main FDSAPP is starting the App with StartView. From StartView I'm switching to NewPCapView and editing some stuff. So when I press Apply the text in protocollTextArea should change to "Pcap created and saved..."

Here is the Code:

```
public class View{
    ...
   public TextArea mainTextArea = new TextArea("--Framework Data Streams--\n     
   --A Framework to create and to merge Pcaps :D--"),
   protocollTextArea = new TextArea("Just showing what you did");
    ...
 }



public class NewPCapView extends View{
    ...
    public void init(){     
        ...
        //alle Listener
        apply.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
               @Override
               public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                   applypressed = true;
                   try {
                    String filename = "InhaltOwnPCap.xml";
                    that.getControl().makeXMLFromOwnPcap(filename);

                    that.getControl().getContentFromXMLForOwnPcap(filename);

                    that.closeSecondStage();

                    protocollTextArea.setText("Pcap created and saved  
                    under C://Temp/outputfile.pcap");

                    that.primaryStage.toFront();

                    System.out.println(protocollTextArea.getText());

                   }catch (XMLStreamException | FileNotFoundException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });

        ...
}


public class StartView extends View{
    ...

    /**
     * Listener
     */
    public void initListener(){
        ...
        createOwnPCap.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                that.makePCapViewUI();
            }
        });     
    }

    public void initCenter(){
        hBox1 = new HBox();
        mainTextArea.setMinWidth(600);
        mainTextArea.setEditable(true);
        textAreaCSS(mainTextArea);
        hBox1.getChildren().add(mainTextArea);
    }

    ....

    public void initRight(){
        vBox = new VBox();
        protocollTextArea.setEditable(false);
        protocollTextArea.setWrapText(true);
        Label protokoll = new Label("Protocoll: ");
        Button save = new Button("Save");

        //Bereich Protokoll
        protokollCSS(protokoll);

        //Bereich TextArea
        textAreaCSS(protocollTextArea);

        //Speichern fehlt noch

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(protokoll,protocollTextArea,save);
    }


    /**
     * Helpingmethods
     */
    public void protokollCSS(Label protokoll){
        protokoll.setStyle("-fx-border-color: grey; "
                +"-fx-border-width: 1;"
                +"-fx-background-color: white");
    }

    public void textAreaCSS(TextArea textArea){
        textArea.setPrefRowCount(20); textArea.setPrefColumnCount(25);
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-border-color: grey;"
                         +"-fx-border-width: 1");
    }
    ...
}


    public class FDSApp extends Application {
      private FDSApp that = this;
      public Stage secondStage;
      public Stage primaryStage;
      public BorderPane root;
      private StartView startView;
      private NewPCapView pCapView;
      private Controller controller;
      private Scene mainScene = null;

      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        root = new BorderPane();
        startView = new StartView(that);
        pCapView = new NewPCapView(that);
        controller = new Controller(that,pCapView);
        initUI(primaryStage);
    }

    public void initUI(Stage primaryStage){
        //Fenster konfigurieren und anzeigen
        primaryStage.setTitle("...");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        //Hintergrund
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightsteelblue");
        root.setTop(startView.getHBox());
        root.setCenter(startView.getHBox1());
        root.setLeft(startView.getHBox2());
        root.setRight(startView.getVBox());

        Scene mainScene = new  
                     Scene(root,startView.getWidth(),startView.getHeight());
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void makePCapViewUI(){
        primaryStage.toBack(); //Macht die Primary invisible
        secondStage = new Stage();
        secondStage.setTitle("Creating PCap");
        secondStage.setScene(pCapView.getPCapScene());
        secondStage.show();
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to set the cursor position to see the update.  In other words if the cursor is at the end of the text and all the text is scrolled up where it isn't visible, you won't see the update.  If you can produce a compilable example that exhibits the problem, we might be able to show you a fix.

Comment: Tried it with protocollTextArea.positionCaret(0); in NewPCapView init().
Doesn't work. The integer in positionCaret is for the line I think? Isn't it?

Comment: This still needs a compilable example.  TextArea works, so it must be in your code.

Comment: Ok I found a solution. I don't know why but I is working if I put the Initialisation of TextArea in StartView-Class.